# Create a custom XML serializer in c# to help the xml doc get converted to object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a xml format in following format mentioned below:-

```
<JobRunnerPluginStaus PluginName="JobRun">                        
  <JobstepStatus>
    <JobStatus StepNumber="1" StepStatus="Done"/>
    <JobStatus StepNumber="2" StepStatus="Started" />                     
  </JobstepStatus>
</JobRunnerPluginStaus>
```

I want to get it converted to following class object using Generics and Reflection.

I want to convert the attributes to simple type(PluginName) and the nested property to a list object(JobstepStatus).

```
public class JobRunnerPluginStaus
{
    public List<JobStatus> JobstepStatus { get; set; }
    public string PluginName { get; set; }
}
public class JobStatus
{
    public int StepNumber { get; set; }
    public string StepStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And what´s your problem? What did you try? Where *specifically* are you stuck?

Comment: Can you modify the classes in your source-code to append xmlserializer-attributes?

Comment: I cannot do that, its for the existing application. It needs to be a scalable helper class. I am passing a parameters Deserialize(string data, Type typeName) where data is the xml string, Type is JobRunnerPluginStaus. I am extracting IEnumerable<XElement> children from it I am trying to map xlelement nodes to list type if there is no attributes and map the attributes to simple type under the parent node.

Comment: @SudiptoSarkar You have to mention all these in your question while asking. You can not put conditions later.

Comment: Do you have any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use sites like: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/
to do the dirty work for me.

Below is how your class hierarchy would look like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="JobStatus")]
    public class JobStatus {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="StepNumber")]
        public string StepNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="StepStatus")]
        public string StepStatus { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="JobstepStatus")]
    public class JobstepStatus {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="JobStatus")]
        public List<JobStatus> JobStatus { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="JobRunnerPluginStaus")]
    public class JobRunnerPluginStaus {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="JobstepStatus")]
        public JobstepStatus JobstepStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="PluginName")]
        public string PluginName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You don´t need an `XmlRoot` on every class, just on that class that actually serves as xml-root. However it won´t hurt anyway.